# How to use move constructor with 2d array (**<type>)?

Tags: c++

It might be that I have coded my class incorrectly, but when I use the move constructor instead of the copy cotr (as one of the overloads not instead to be precise), my program crushes:

For example:

```
class Sample
{
    int a;
    int **b;
    //constructor declarations
}
```

And in the .cpp file:

```
Sample::Sample(Sample &&other)
    : a(a), b(b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        other.b[i] = nullptr;
    other.b = nullptr;
    other.a = 0;
}
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: What is the value of `n`?

Comment: I made some slight edits, because I copied the code from my project I forgot to edit that part, sorry.

Comment: You copy pointer value 'b' but you modify the value that pointer points to and set it to 0, so the new objects 'b' pointer will point to zero too. So your program might crash if you do something like this: **b.

Comment: So I should delete everything between {}? Or should I implicitly copy every "row"?

Comment: A move constructor doesn't have to turn the source object into mush.

Comment: @PeteBecker It depends what copy you want to make. But from your code, i understood that you want to zero out the old object, so you should be good just by removing 'for' loop

Comment: Sorry, last comment was directed to @adadaae12313412

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you could move the values:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

class Sample
{
    int a;
    int **b;
public:
    Sample(int a, int** b) : a{a}, b{b} {}
    Sample(Sample &&other);
    // still missing a destructor that will get rid of the new'd ints
    void print();
};

Sample::Sample(Sample &&other)
    : a(other.a), b(other.b)
{
    //for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    //  other.b[i] = nullptr; // this should not be done, the new b has a pointer to these values
    other.b = nullptr;
    other.a = 0;
}

void Sample::print()
{
    if(a == 0 && b == nullptr)
        std::cout << "this object is empty!";
    for(size_t i{0}; i < a; ++i) {
        std::cout << *b[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    Sample s{5,{new int*[5]{new int{0}, new int{1}, new int{2}, new int{3}, new int{4}}}};
    auto c{std::move(s)};
    // c now has c.b as a pointer an array of pointers
    s.print();
    c.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i made some edits to my class and it works even without std::move thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ill just recap my comment above and put it as an answer. You copied 'b' pointer but you modified the values that pointer points to. The new object will get correct pointer 'b' but the value that pointer points to is modified as well, in this case it will point to number zero. You are using pointer to a pointer so at some point your new object might try to dereference the pointers and as a result of a dereferencing a null pointer bad things happen.

Comment: Can you provide an edit to my constructor so it does what it's supposed to do, because I'm still not sure on how to do that?