# Move constructor of 2d array in c++(Logic of syntax is not clear):

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to implement Matrix class with the help of pointers:

```
class Matrix{
private:
    int row;
    int col;
    double elem**
public:
    //Default Constructor:
    Matrix(int row,int col);
    //Initialized list constructor:
    Matrix(initializer_list<initializer_list<double>> lst);
    //Destructor
    ~Matrix();
    //Copy constructor
    Matrix(const Matrix& other);
    //Copy assingment
    Matrix operator=(const Matrix& other);
    //Move constructor
    Matrix(Matrix&& other);
    //Move assingment
    Matrix operator=(Matrix&& other);
```

But I have problem with creating moving constructor and assingment:
I have found similar post([How to use move constructor with 2d array (**<type>)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40332379/how-to-use-move-constructor-with-2d-array-type)) and based on that post I created my move constructor and move assingment:

```
//Move assingment
Matrix operator=(Matrix&& other){
    for(int i = 0;i<row;++i){
        delete[] elem[i];
    }
    delete[] elem;
    elem = other.elem;
    row = other.row;
    col = other.col;
    other.elem = nullptr;
    other.row = 0;
    other.col = 0;
    return *this;

}



//Move constructor
Matrix::Matrix(Matrix&& other):
    row{other.row},
    col{other.col},
    elem{other.row}
    {
        other.elem = nullptr;
        other.row = 0;
        other.col = 0;

    }
```

But I didn't understand the logic. Why can we just assign the pointer to pointers 2d array like this: `elem = other.elem;` and `elem{other.row}`

Shouldn't we assign elements for each row separately using for loop? like `elem[i] = new double[other.col]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets take it step by step:

1. The move assignment operator function or move constructor is called
2. `other.elem` points to some memory
3. With `elem = other.elem` you now have two pointers pointing to the same memory
4. With `other.elem = nullptr` only `this->elem` is pointing to that memory

It's really no different than e.g.

```
int a;
int b;

a = 5;   // Corresponds to the initialization of other.elem
b = a;   // Corresponds to elem = other.elem
a = 0;   // Corresponds to other.elem = nullptr
```

Answer (score 0):

`moving` means stealing.

Just snatch what `other` has.You make `elem` point to `other`'s memory and now you own it and make `other` point to `null`.
The whole point of `move` is to avoid a copy, so you don't do a row wise copy.Row wise copy makes sense in copy construction and copy assignment when you want you(`this`) and `other` both to have independent resources.